# The sed command is not working with regex

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I'm parsing the output of a **HTTP GET** request with `sed` to retrieve the contents of a given html tag. The result of that request is like this:

`"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>Hello!</h1><p>v1.0.4-b</p></body></html>"`

And I want to retrieve the version number inside the p element.

However, `sed` seems to have a bug in **regex** parsing.
When I use:

`sed 's/.*<p>//'`

It correctly replaces the text at the left of the version (i.e., it outputs `"v1.0.4-b</p></body></html>"`). But, when I try to use regex groups, with

`sed 's/.*<p>(.*)<\/p>.*/\1/'`

It fails to match and gives an error:

`` sed: -e expression #1, char 20: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS. ``

Despite that, when I test the **regex** on online regex validators it works.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```sh
sed -n 's~.*<p>\([^<]*\)</p>.*~\1~p'
sed -n -E 's~.*<p>([^<]*)</p>.*~\1~p'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Re0x7Y):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sed -n 's~.*<p>\([^<]*\)</p>.*~\1~p' <<< \
 "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>Hello!</h1><p>v1.0.4-b</p></body></html>"
## => v1.0.4-b
```

The `sed 's/.*<p>(.*)<\p>.*/\1/'` command would not work because

- You are using a POSIX BRE pattern where the unescaped `(` and `)` are treated as literal parentheses chars, not a capturing group. In POSIX BRE, you need `\(...\)` to define a capturing group (this is why you get the *`invalid reference \1`* exception)
- If you add `-E` option to enable POSIX ERE, you can use `(...)` to define a capturing group
- You are not matching `/p`, you have `\p` in the pattern.

As there are slashes in the pattern, it is more convenient to choose regex delimiters other than `/`, I chose `~` here.

Also, I used `-n` option to suppress default line output and `p` flag to print only the result of the substitution.

Comment: Can you explain why mine is not working and yours is?

Comment: @AndréRosa I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: Yes, thank you!. I have an additional doubt: why do you use [^<]* inside of the group ?

Comment: @AndréRosa I am accustomed to using negated bracket expressions that allow matching more precisely. `.*` would fail if there are more `</p>`s in the string.